# Identity (on database creation) error specified key was too long

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I have here an issue with AspNet Identity and MySql, the issue is error which is really blocking me, this error is following:

> specified key was too long max key length is 767 bytes

Now I followed this tutorial of using MySql with Identity:

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/security/aspnet-identity-using-mysql-storage-with-an-entityframework-mysql-provider

I want to say I had progression, because now atleast i get some tables generated in MySQL, but I'm stack on this issue, for a long time i'm trying to solve this, but without success.

The error i get is in this part:

```
 public void InitializeDatabase(ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            if (!context.Database.Exists())
            {
                // if database did not exist before - create it
                context.Database.Create();
            }
            else
            {
                // query to check if MigrationHistory table is present in the database 
                var migrationHistoryTableExists = ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreQuery<int>(
                string.Format(
                  "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = '{0}' AND table_name = '__MigrationHistory'",
                  "Server=127.0.0.1;Database=mydb;uid=root;pwd=mypass;port=3351;"));

                // if MigrationHistory table is not there (which is the case first time we run) - create it
                if (migrationHistoryTableExists.FirstOrDefault() == 0)
                {
                    context.Database.Delete();
                    context.Database.Create(); //<<<< i get here error
                }
            }
        }
```

So this throws error : `context.Database.Create();`

I tried to investigate what exactly is the problem but i couldn't find :(

I tried comparing the data in sql server generated database and put the same info in the migrationtable, and normally i can put the same values in there from insert statement in workbench.

Maybe anyone can help me to get through this?

Just to notice, at the end all of the tables are created but nothing is inserted, because of the error :/

Here are all the tables that are created in mysql schema:
[image: mysql columns]

I have a small update:
It seems that it tries to make a combined PK from the 2 columns migrationId and contextkey, that is why you get this kind of error.

I could reproduce it in my workbench i tried to alter table, by setting those columns as PK's and i got exactly the same error. But how do I say that only 1 PK should be set for example?

Comment: I think your problem is related to this: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=68453

For InnoDB, by default, an index key for a single-column index can be up to 767 bytes. If it's a unique key, this error gets thrown; if it's not unique, it gets truncated silently.

Comment: But i tried to add some values there, and it was fine ... i dont know how big stuff it is trying to add there ... and as well i set there a limit on this fields, if you checked the tutorial

Comment: What's the size of the aspnetUsers.UserName column in the database?

Comment: as you can see username is longtext

Comment: One of the answers here worked for me:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24981593/specified-key-was-too-long-max-key-length-is-767-bytes-mysql-error-in-entity-fr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is caused by UTF-8 columns that are too long and are being used as indexes. The best way to solve this would be to use a different database engine, but that is probably not the thing you want to hear. The second choice is to update the database schema to lower the limit of characters in the indexed fields.

http://wildlyinaccurate.com/mysql-specified-key-was-too-long-max-key-length-is-767-bytes

EDIT:
The error is doscussed here: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=70940 . The last post seems to offer a viable slution.

Comment: I checked this link already, but as i said before in the tutorial i set the limit for those columns and i checked the values that are being added are not that big, and manually i can add them ...

Comment: Could you perhaps post a glimpse of the database schema? Because of the size of UTF characters the multiplication there could easily overflow the allowed column size, but it is unusual that you are able to add them manually. Hasn't something changed in the newest schema?

Comment: Ok, i've placed an image of all the column that are being created

Comment: Apparently it is the ContextKey column that is causing the problems, but I'm not sure it is possible to change the size...

Comment: Updated my answer with a lig to MySQL bug center, they seem to have a solution

Comment: Okay, but what they have suggested i use it in the tutorial, if you have seen the code, i have exactly the same ...

Comment: I updated my post, i think it is when setting 2 primary keys you get this issue

Comment: Ok, it was solved honestly it was a stupid mistake, i had this: base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder); after my code, which i supposed all my overwritten action has ignored :)

Comment: Congratulations for the solution :-) ! That is really something one can easily miss..

Answer (score 3):

Through checking the SQL queries generated by EF, I had found that the problem was related to UserName (varchar utf8 256) in table AspNetUsers and Name (varchar utf8 256) in table AspNetRoles, while the table for HistoryRow was fine.

So the following codes resolved the problem.

```
    public class WebPortalDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public WebPortalDbContext()
        : base("IdentityConnection")
    {

    }

    public static WebPortalDbContext Create()
    {
        return new WebPortalDbContext();
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityRole>()
            .Property(c => c.Name).HasMaxLength(128).IsRequired();

        modelBuilder.Entity<Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityUser>().ToTable("AspNetUsers")//I have to declare the table name, otherwise IdentityUser will be created
            .Property(c => c.UserName).HasMaxLength(128).IsRequired();
    }


}
```

To clarify the solution, here's the libraries I am using:

1. EF 6.1.0
2. Microsoft ASP.NET Identity EntityFramework 2.0.0
3. ASP.NET Identity Owin 2.0.0
4. MySql .NET libraries 6.8.3

And this solution also works for

1. EF 6.1.1
2. Microsoft ASP.NET Identity EntityFramework 2.0.1
3. ASP.NET Identity Owin 2.0.1

Comment: I was able to set maxlength to 255 (the default is 256). We must not forget to recreate the initial explicit migration after changing modelbuilder configurations on our derived dbcontext.

Comment: You need to change the `IdentityUser` to `ApplicationUser` to make this work.

Answer (score 0):

Just a shot in the dark ... I think the column that's being created for Application.UserName is too large for a unique index. See if you can influence the size of it by overriding the default:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
  [StringLength(200)]
  public override string UserName { get; set; }   
}
```

Comment: No, it isn't username i tested it now, and i get same error and then again the username i provide myself and it is only 4 letters 'test', i think it is more the migrationhistory table, but yeah ...