# Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes Mysql error in Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have start working on Asp.net Mvc-5 application using visual studio 2012. So I have downloaded Entity Framework-6 and MySQL 6.8.3.0 from nuget. When I tried to create database by using db Context command

```
dbContext.Database.CreateIfNotExists();
```

This exception thrown.

> Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes

I have done search on it, but cannot find any solution. One thing that I got during my search, this can be Unicode characters problem. I don't know how to deal with this issue.

**Updated**

I am using following configuration

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <entityFramework>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
      <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.8.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
</configuration>
```

My DB Context class. I have removed all the models just keep left one model

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public MyContext()
        : base("myconn")
    {
        this.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions.PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }

    public DbSet<ModelOne> ModelOne { get; set; }

}
```

Model class

```
public class  ModelOne
{
        [Key]
        public int CreatedId { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> UserId { get; set; }
        public Nullable<DateTime> Date { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
  }
```

Can anyone help me with this issue?

Thank you.

Comment: It is possible to support Code-First and migrations with MySQL, but requires a change in configuration.  see http://blog.devart.com/entity-framework-6-support-for-oracle-mysql-postgresql-sqlite-and-salesforce.html

Comment: I am using same configuration but still facing the same issue

Comment: do you have an example of the Configuration class where you register for Code-First and migrations? i.e. `this.SetSqlGenerator()` ....

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I have changed the DbConfigurationType of DbContext.

Got from this this link [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21120732/1558544)

Now it is working

```
[DbConfigurationType(typeof(MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlEFConfiguration))]
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public MyContext()
        : base("myconn")
    {
        this.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;
    }

    static MyContext()
    {
            DbConfiguration.SetConfiguration(new MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlEFConfiguration());
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions.PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }

    public DbSet<ModelOne> ModelOne { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm!  I only had to add the attribute to the class and things took off perfectly.

Comment: Worked for me, just had to do the attribute as well. I think the method variation is for those who don't want to decorate with attributes.

Comment: In fact, just using [DbConfigurationType(typeof(MySqlEFConfiguration))] in assembly is enough.

Answer (score 5):

If you're using ASP.NET Identity then there are 3 places where this is happening

1. In the migration history table
2. The Name property of IdentityRole
3. The Username and Email property of ApplicationUser

Most articles I came across has a solution that basically reduce the length of Username and Email to 128 character. However, i found this is unacceptable because the official spec for email address is 256 ansi characters.

My solution was to :

1. Turn unicode off for Email and Username
2. override MySqlMigrationSqlGenerator and tell it to use latin1_general_ci collate, which is ansi character set.
3. reduce the length of role name. This is acceptable as role name doesn't need to be that long
4. reduce key length for history migration as described in various articles on the Internet.

You can find my solution at https://github.com/timdinhdotcom/MySql.AspNetIdentity

Comment: +1 That solve my problem when migration execute `CREATE UNIQUE index  UserNameIndex on ApplicationUsers (UserName DESC) using HASH` and die.

Answer (score 4):

If you have tried all the answers in this post and still getting the error, then try running this command on MySQL server:

```
set GLOBAL storage_engine='InnoDb';
```

The bug was reported here: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=4541

Comment: Feel like this should have been the accepted answer. Here is another thread containing this solution: https://confluence.atlassian.com/fishkb/mysql-database-migration-fails-with-specified-key-was-too-long-max-key-length-is-1000-bytes-298978735.html

Answer (score 3):

Use the configuration code below... This solved my problem:

```
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<MDbContext>
{       
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
        CommandTimeout = 3600;

        DbConfiguration.SetConfiguration(new MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlEFConfiguration());
        SetSqlGenerator(MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlProviderInvariantName.ProviderName, new MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlMigrationSqlGenerator());
        SetHistoryContextFactory(MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlProviderInvariantName.ProviderName, (connection, schema) => new MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlHistoryContext(connection, schema));
    }

}
```

Comment: Flawless. This is exactly the correct answer. I saw remnants of this listed elsewhere in articles, and was hoping to find in this thread more explicitly as so. 100% success. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/788357/How-to-set-up-application-using-ASP-NET-Identity-w) and see if it helps. Especially the `MySqlHistoryContext.cs`, `Configuration.cs` and `MySqlInitializer.cs` classes added.

This is where you will find your solution.

```
public class MySqlHistoryContext : HistoryContext
    {
        public MySqlHistoryContext(DbConnection connection, string defaultSchema)
            : base(connection, defaultSchema)
        {

        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            modelBuilder.Entity<HistoryRow>().Property(h => h.MigrationId).HasMaxLength(100).IsRequired();
            modelBuilder.Entity<HistoryRow>().Property(h => h.ContextKey).HasMaxLength(200).IsRequired();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

There are simple way to change NVARCHAR fields to varchar in MYSQl add this lines in IdentityModels.cs

```
[DbConfigurationType(typeof(MySqlEFConfiguration))]
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, Role, int, UserLogin, UserRole, UserClaim>
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        //troca todos os campos NVARCHAR por varchar
        modelBuilder.Properties().Where(x =>
          x.PropertyType.FullName.Equals("System.String") &&
         !x.GetCustomAttributes(false).OfType<ColumnAttribute>().Where(q => q.TypeName != null && q.TypeName.Equals("varchar(max)", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)).Any())
          .Configure(c =>
             c.HasColumnType("varchar(65000)"));

        modelBuilder.Properties().Where(x =>
          x.PropertyType.FullName.Equals("System.String") &&
         !x.GetCustomAttributes(false).OfType<ColumnAttribute>().Where(q => q.TypeName != null && q.TypeName.Equals("nvarchar", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)).Any())
          .Configure(c =>
             c.HasColumnType("varchar"));
    }

    public ApplicationDbContext()  : base("DefaultConnection")
    {

    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to see this link 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/27082231/929740

- Adding the DbConfigurationTypeAttribute on the context class:
  [DbConfigurationType(typeof(MySqlEFConfiguration))]
- Calling DbConfiguration.SetConfiguration(new MySqlEFConfiguration()) at the application startup
- Set the DbConfiguration type in the configuration file:

> < entityFramework codeConfigurationType="MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlEFConfiguration, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6">

Answer (score 0):

I got rid of this issue by running:

```
Enable-Migrations -EnableAutomaticMigrations -Force -ContextTypeName ApplicationDbContext
```

And without creating an Initial migration:

```
Update-Database
```

The tables were created without any problem nor errors