# Identity and Mysql in Code First - Specified key was too long; max key length is 1000 bytes

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-2.0, entity-framework-migrations

I am trying to create a CodeFirst Database with IentityCore using MySQL driver.

My **User** DbModel is like this-

```
[Table("User")]
public class User : IdentityUser<int>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

and **Role**  DBModel is like this-

```
[Table("Role")]
public class Role : IdentityRole<int>
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

My DbContext is like this-

```
public class InventoryManagementDbContext : IdentityDbContext<User, Role, int>
{
    //Table List
    public DbSet<Employee> Employies { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ProductCategory> ProductCategorys { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ProductType> ProductTypes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Entry> Entries { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Exit> Exits { get; set; }
    //Table List End

    public InventoryManagementDbContext(DbContextOptions<InventoryManagementDbContext> options)
    : base(options)
    {}

    //Fluent API to make Composite Key
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        // email address doesn't need to be in unicode, check it spec
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>().Property(u => u.UserName).IsUnicode(false);
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>().Property(u => u.Email).IsUnicode(false);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Role>().Property(r => r.Name).HasMaxLength(255);
    }
}
```

So, I have disabled Unicode for Email and Username and also set MaxLength for **Role.Name**.

Still if I am trying to execute this command-

> Add-Migration

Then I am getting this error-

```
.....................................
.....................................

fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20102]
      Failed executing DbCommand (13ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='60']
      CREATE TABLE `AspNetUserLogins` (
          `LoginProvider` varchar(767) NOT NULL,
          `ProviderKey` varchar(767) NOT NULL,
          `ProviderDisplayName` text NULL,
          `UserId` int NOT NULL,
          PRIMARY KEY (`LoginProvider`, `ProviderKey`),
          CONSTRAINT `FK_AspNetUserLogins_AspNetUsers_UserId` FOREIGN KEY (`UserId`) REFERENCES `AspNetUsers` (`Id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
      );
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Specified key was too long; max key length is 1000 bytes
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadPacket()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.GetResult(Int32& affectedRow, Int64& insertedId)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.NextResult(Int32 statementId, Boolean force)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.NextResult()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteNonQueryAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.<ExecuteAsync>d__17.MoveNext()
failverbose: Found DbContext 'InventoryManagementDbContext'.
: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20102]
      Failed executing DbCommand (13ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='60']
      CREATE TABLE `AspNetUserLogins` (
          `LoginProvider` varchar(767) NOT NULL,
          `ProviderKey` varchar(767) NOT NULL,
          `ProviderDisplayName` text NULL,
          `UserId` int NOT NULL,
          PRIMARY KEY (`LoginProvider`, `ProviderKey`),
          CONSTRAINT `FK_AspNetUserLogins_AspNetUsers_UserId` FOREIGN KEY (`UserId`) REFERENCES `AspNetUsers` (`Id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
      );
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Specified key was too long; max key length is 1000 bytes
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadPacket()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.GetResult(Int32& affectedRow, Int64& insertedId)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.NextResult(Int32 statementId, Boolean force)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.NextResult()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteNonQueryAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.<ExecuteAsync>d__17.MoveNext()
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure[10403]
      Entity Framework Core 2.0.2-rtm-10011 initialized 'InventoryManagementDbContext' using provider 'MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore' with options: NoTracking CommandTimeout=60 
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure[10403]
      Entity Framework Core 2.0.2-rtm-10011 initialized 'InventoryManagementDbContext' using provider 'MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore' with options: NoTracking CommandTimeout=60
```

My complete code can be found in **[here](https://github.com/AbrarJahin/ASP.NetCore-MySQL-Login-CRUD/tree/login)**.

Can anyone please help?

### Re-

[**This** question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24981593/specified-key-was-too-long-max-key-length-is-767-bytes-mysql-error-in-entity-fr) is not solving my question because I was not facing any problem for General Keys, they are perfectly working for me.

I am getting problem when trying to use [***Identity***](https://www.asp.net/identity).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes Mysql error in Entity Framework 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24981593/specified-key-was-too-long-max-key-length-is-767-bytes-mysql-error-in-entity-fr)

Comment: It is not a duplicate, I have added answer for that at the end of te question

Comment: Moreover I am using Int as ID, not string in Identity

Comment: Sorry I did miss that it was a "duplicate link" for the duplicate.

Comment: Set max length of 127 for loginprovider and providerkey

Answer (score 3):

I'll leave this here even though it's been a while since the question, for anyone with the same problem.

You need to set the max length for a few properties for:

- IdentityRole
- IdentityUser
- IdentityUserLogin
- IdentityUserToken

In this case, you have extended the classes `IdentityUser` and `IdentityRole` for using an `integer` PK, so your code, using the fluent API, should be like this:

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    int stringMaxLength = /* something like 100*/;
    // User IdentityRole and IdentityUser in case you haven't extended those classes
    builder.Entity<Role>(x => x.Property(m => m.Name).HasMaxLength(stringMaxLength));
    builder.Entity<Role>(x => x.Property(m => m.NormalizedName).HasMaxLength(stringMaxLength));
    builder.Entity<User>(x => x.Property(m => m.NormalizedUserName).HasMaxLength(stringMaxLength));

    // We are using int here because of the change on the PK
    builder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin<int>>(x => x.Property(m => m.LoginProvider).HasMaxLength(stringMaxLength));
    builder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin<int>>(x => x.Property(m => m.ProviderKey).HasMaxLength(stringMaxLength));

    // We are using int here because of the change on the PK
    builder.Entity<IdentityUserToken<int>>(x => x.Property(m => m.LoginProvider).HasMaxLength(stringMaxLength));
    builder.Entity<IdentityUserToken<int>>(x => x.Property(m => m.Name).HasMaxLength(stringMaxLength));

   // etc..
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: It looks like MySQL 8 is using utf8mb4 by default and that's why key fields are getting out of limits. So more proper solution might to set up `.ForMySQLHasCharset("latin1")` for `IdentityUserLogin` and `IdentityUserToken` entities:
`modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserToken<Guid>>().ForMySQLHasCharset("latin1");`