# Migration of ASP.NET MVC MySql db to PLESK

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, database-migration, production-environment

I have published my Asp.NET project to the Plesk, It was done successfully.
Now I need to update database using PM but it creates table for 'ASPNETROLES' then throws the exception.

> Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes

I have found the following solutions but none worked:

https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=81817

[Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes Mysql error in Entity Framework 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24981593/specified-key-was-too-long-max-key-length-is-767-bytes-mysql-error-in-entity-fr)

I have tried the following code but failed :

```
[DbConfigurationType(typeof(MySqlEFConfiguration))]
public class AppIdentityDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public AppIdentityDbContext() : base("myConnection")
    {

    }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Entity<HistoryRow>().HasKey<string>(h => h.MigrationId);
        modelBuilder.Entity<HistoryRow>().Property(h => h.MigrationId).HasMaxLength(100).IsRequired();
        modelBuilder.Entity<HistoryRow>().Property(h => h.ContextKey).HasMaxLength(200).IsRequired();
        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().Property(u => u.Id).HasMaxLength(128);
        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().Property(u => u.UserName).HasMaxLength(128);
        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().Property(u => u.Email).HasMaxLength(128);
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().Property(r => r.Name).HasMaxLength(128);

}
```

It should create all ASPNET tables should also set the primary key to auto increment.

Can someone please share a guide for deployment on Plesk?